# Deleting entry from Database via PHP Select Form - not deleting entry

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to delete an entry from my database using an HTML form. However, when it's submitted, the entry doesn't get deleted from the database and no error code is displayed to say why.

Could somebody possibly let me know if I'm missing something from my code, just in case I've over-looked something?

Thank you.

```
<form method="post" action="./removeBook.inc.php">
<select name="books">
<option>Please select the Book you wish to delete:</option>
<?php
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=csdm-mysql;dbname=db1001550_book_management";
    $username = "1001550";
    $password = "1001550";
    // try connecting to the database
    $con = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    // turn on PDO exception handling 
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // enter catch block in event of error in preceding try block
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

try {                                          
    $sql=("SELECT * FROM books");                                          
    $results = $con->query($sql);                                                                                  
    if ($results->rowcount() == 0) {
        echo "<p>No books found. </p><br />";
    } else {     
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $book_id=$row['book_id'];                                    
            echo "<option value=\"".$book_id."\">".$book_id."</option>";
        } 
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

mysql_close();
?>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove Book" style="width:auto;">
</form>
```

And here is the code within the form submitted page:

```
<?php                            
$host="csdm-mysql"; // Host name 
$username="1001550"; // Mysql username 
$password="1001550"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db1001550_book_management"; // Database name  

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("Cannot select DB");

if (isset($_POST['books'])) {
    $books=$_POST['books']; 
}

// Remove data from database 
$result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM books WHERE book_id=$books");

// if successfully deleted from database, prompt will say book was deleted. 
if ($result) {
    print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    print "alert('Book has been deleted successfully!')";
    print "</script>";
} else {
    print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    print "alert('Book was not deleted')";
    print "</script>";
}

// close connection
mysql_close();
?>

<form method="post" action="./removeBook.inc.php">
                              <select name="books">
                                  <option>Please select the Book you wish to delete:</option>
                                  <option value='B0001'>B0001</option><option value='B0002'>B0002</option><option value='B0003'>B0003</option><option value='B0004'>B0004</option><option value='B0005'>B0005</option><option value='B0006'>B0006</option><option value='B0007'>B0007</option><option value='B0008'>B0008</option><option value='B0009'>B0009</option><option value='B0010'>B0010</option><option value='B0011'>B0011</option><option value='B0012'>B0012</option><option value='B0013'>B0013</option><option value='B0014'>B0014</option><option value='B0015'>B0015</option><option value='B0016'>B0016</option><option value='B0017'>B0017</option><option value='B0018'>B0018</option><option value='B0019'>B0019</option><option value='B0020'>B0020</option>                                      
                              </select>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove Book" style="width:auto;">
                            </form>
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Is `$book_id` string or int?

Comment: Give us the rendered html of the <select>

Comment: It's a string - book_id char(5)

Comment: @RoyalBg sorry, what do you mean by rendered html?

Comment: when you open the page and you are about to select book_id from the dropdown, open View Source and copy the HTML with the select tag and the option tags, to see what PHP has generated for you. Also make `var_dump($_POST)` in the submitted page and give us the output

Comment: btw. why both pages connect to db... with different api's

Comment: I'm currently working with another person, so that's why they are different.

Answer (score 1):

Try to print and see whether you are getting the selected Book ID.
Whenever you get a prob in query print and see.

add this line

```
print "DELETE FROM books WHERE book_id=$books";
```

before

```
$result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM books WHERE book_id=$books");
```

I think you did not receive the Book Id in proper format.

Change the line

```
 echo "<option value=\"".$book_id."\">".$book_id."</option>";
```

as

```
 echo "<option value='".$book_id."'>".$book_id."</option>";
```

And also use single quotes to encapsulate a value.
Change

```
 $result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM books WHERE book_id=$books");
```

to

```
 $result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM books WHERE book_id='".$books."'");
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the above changes to options and $result and it still did not remove my selected value from my database.
when typing the print line, I receive the correct value back
`DELETE FROM books WHERE book_id=B0020`

Comment: Have you printed the query? What is it printing? Can you post the query that gets printed in the screen?

Comment: `mysql_query("DELETE FROM books WHERE book_id=$books") or die(mysql_error());` there should be MySQL error then, because everything else seems OK syntactially. You might not have permissions to DELETE

Comment: @RoyalBg I receive this printed when I replace my code with yours...
`DELETE FROM books WHERE book_id=B0020Unknown column 'B0020' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @KannanRajendran this is the code that's printed to the screen when I use your print query...
`DELETE FROM books WHERE book_id=B0020`

Comment: @Kimberrley now quote the book_id value `mysql_query("DELETE FROM books WHERE book_id='".$books."'") or die(mysql_error());` and give the output again

Comment: Go to PHPMyAdmin and execute this query. You will be notified with a syntax error. The error is it is not encapsulated with single quotes. You have to change the delete query to $result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM books WHERE book_id='".$books."'"); Do a cross check whether book_id B0020 is there in the table :)

Comment: The code worked and put out the error about a foreign key constraint... my coding partner just explained we need to remove the book from another database before being able to delete it.

Comment: Thats good. So when you feel that your SQL is not working, Print it, copy it, execute it in the DB directly. This way, you can classify the issue whether it is a code error or the SQL error. It is a matter of time to find the problem that makes easy to resolve. God luck :)

Comment: Error handling :) I guess mysql_error() also returned the foreign key error

Answer (score 0):

IF your book_id field is varchar or text, you should add quotes between $books

```
...WHERE book_id='$books'
```

Comment: Hi, just tried adding that and the book entry was still not deleted. :(